# Uptime under linux in C

Tags: c, linux

How can I retrieve uptime under linux using C? (without using popen and/or /proc)

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Via `top` or via `uptime`, but I don't know about any syscall, someone will for sure :)

`uptime` should be rather easy to parse.

Just stumbled into this:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

struct sysinfo info;
sysinfo(&info);
printf("Uptime = %ld\n", info.uptime);
```

Comment: Horray for sysinfo() :) NB: `struct sysinfo` is rather 'shifty' between 2.4 (early) 2.4 (late) and 2.6. If your code is likely to be used for appliances, its handy to run build checks to see what members might be different.

Comment: printf("Uptime: %02ld:%02ld:%02ld\n", info.uptime/3600, info.uptime%3600/60, info.uptime%60);

Comment: However, `<sys/sysinfos>` doesn't seem to exist when you're compiling the kernel (vagrant & trusty64) :/ How to do in that situation?

Answer (score 2):

If its there and contains the member `uptime`, `struct sysinfo` is the preferred way to go, as [Jack explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070278/uptime-under-linux-in-c/3070305#3070305).

The other way is to read `btime` out of `/proc/stat` , then just subtract it from the current time. `btime` is just a UNIX epoch indicating when the kernel booted.

That gives you the # of seconds since boot, which you can then translate into years / months / days / hours / etc. This saves having to deal with strings in `/proc/uptime`. If `btime` isn't there, and `struct sysinfo` has no member named `uptime`, you have to parse `/proc/uptime`.

For modern kernels, `sysinfo()` should work just fine. Most things still running 2.4 (or earlier) out in the wild are appliances of some kind or other embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

To get the system start time in a more portable way, would be to use "who -b". To use this in a program you would have to spawn a shell and interpret its output. Unfortunately this seems the only place where such an information is available in POSIX, and this also only as an extension.