# How to test system reboot time more than a year?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, unix

I want test code against Linux system which is not rebooted since a year. I didn't find a system which is not rebooted since last two months. Is there a way to simulate it?

I tried a weird way that change system time to a year back and rebooted system and then change date to current time. But that won't solve my problem.

I want to test against big integer counters.

Comment: You want to test something on a machine that has been up for more than 1 year? What for? What are you testing?

Comment: @mat, Code is related to percentage cpu utilization. that's need to be verified against system which is running since long time.

Comment: I don't understand why. What are you worried about?

Comment: Want to test against big integer counters.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to mention that. You should also mention what OS you're working on, and exactly what counters you're interested in since they all might have different wrap-around behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to check latest boot time, for instance:

```
% last reboot | head -n 1
reboot           ~                         Tue Aug 13 09:56

% sysctl kern.boottime
kern.boottime: { sec = 1376377004, usec = 264281 } Tue Aug 13 09:56:44 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to test this as a system test, in which you test the whole program, split the code that accesses the uptime of the system (returning the big integers you are worried about) from the part of the code that performs computations using the up time. Then unit test the latter.

If you are programming in C or C++ on Linux, you might be using the [`sysinfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070278/uptime-under-linux-in-c) system call to get the uptime. In that case you could have your computation code be sent a pointer to a `struct sysinfo`. Your unit tests could fill in whatever large values you wanted for the `sysinfo.uptime` value.