# How to check for computer power loss?

Tags: c, restart, shutdown

Hopefully this is a simple question to answer.

Basically I would like to use C to see if there was a power loss in my computer. This will decide how a program runs. If there was a power loss then it would go one way. Otherwise it would respond another way:

```
#include nopower.h
#include power.h 
//------------------------
if(!powerloss){
  power_procedure();
}
else no_power_procedure(); 
//--------------------------
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm hoping that this can be run directly on the computer running this code. In otherwords is there a way to check a registry status to see if power was loss. The operating system knows when there is an improper shutdown, and I'd like to know if I can tap into the same or a similar resource. I'd rather not constantly write to a file.

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: As a sanity check, this program is supposed to run on a *different* computer, right?

Comment: `if(true){power_procedure();} else {no_power_procedure();}`

Comment: What does "power loss" mean here? That there was a previous power loss, and the system has since booted again? Or is this a laptop, and you want to know if the system is running on battery?  The reason this question was closed, is because you haven't given nearly enough information for us to be able to answer it.

Comment: BeOS had an API for this... http://aicoder.blogspot.com/2011/03/hilarious-system-calls-in-beos.html

Comment: Guys, using C++, how do I do I detect that computer is powered off?

Comment: @VladLazarenko unless your program is running on a separate computer, you can't, because if the computer is off, your program is not running and therefore it cannot do anything.

Comment: If anyone figures out how to make the transistors work on a chip that has no voltage or current supplied to it, let me know... a Nobel prize might be in order.

If you want to check to see if ANOTHER computer is not powered, a simple ping check of that computer's IP could work, provided that the IP address is unique and the network is managed by people more skillful than the clowns I have to deal with.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. And yes Mr. Reinhart I'm attempting to see if there is a way to check for previous power loss other than constantly writing or appending to a file. I would like to have this program run on the same computer that lost power earlier. Its actually a BeagleBone Black but I'm prototyping on my laptop.

Comment: For minimal understanding, I recently went to training at Rockwell Collins and their CMU 900 has the capability written into its code to dump as small amount of memory onto an EEPROM. So that when the box starts back up again it has this information saved. I don't expect to do the same thing because that would be time consuming. But I'm hoping now this question will be released from whatever hold its on.

Comment: @It'sPete My question is not to have access to the state while the system is off. But rather to see if its possible to know whether the machine was shut down appropriately.

Comment: It's not simple to detect power loss. Also, Ubuntu doesn't have a registry (a Windows term). Do you need true power information? The `sysinfo` call allows you to get the time the system has been up (the `uptime` field).  This cannot distinguish between power off and reboot with no power off.  But if this is good enough, your program need only save to a file the clock time it is started. By reading this value, subtracting it from the current clock and comparing to the sysinfo uptime value, it knows whether the system has rebooted since the last time your program started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() 
{    
   printf ("power is currently on");
}
```

Coding the  "power is currently off" case is somewhat trickier.

Alternately if you want to know the time since the last boot, and put up a message if it was recent, then see [Uptime under linux in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070278/uptime-under-linux-in-c)

Comment: Alternatively - The vending machine has gone dead - guess the power is off

Comment: but there are a test for when it goes to UPS

Comment: My god, best joke ever